# I set alarm every 15 min but still it sends data at random timings, not showing when app is closed

Tags: android

Whenever I start my main activity, time is fetching. I want it to happen every 15 min.

for start service

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("MyBroadcast");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("hasNetwork", "inside");
```

after that I am trying to set an alarm every 15 min

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Log.d("hasNetwork","inside");
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final PendingIntent wakeupIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, LocationUpdaterService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final boolean hasNetwork = !intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if (hasNetwork)
        {
```

//here i set the time for repeat after  one minute for testing purpose
               alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60000, wakeupIntent);

```
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("hasNetwork","NO");
            alarmManager.cancel(wakeupIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

this is the class which fetches current location and sends to the server

```
public class LocationUpdaterService extends Service  implements

 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 

GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener




{


    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String lat="",lng="";
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.d("hasNetw1ork", "onlocation???");
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.e("latitude", "latitude--" + latitude+"longitude="+longitude);
        lat= String.valueOf(latitude);
        lng= String.valueOf(longitude);
        try
        {
            Log.e("latitude", "inside latitude--" + latitude);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.d("hasNetwork",location.getLatitude()+"  "+location.getLongitude());
            sendToServer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
      //  Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
          Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

          mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
          mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

          LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {


    }

    private enum State
    {
        IDLE, WORKING;
    }


    private static State state;

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    static
    {
        state = State.IDLE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "LocationUpdaterService");
        Log.d("hasNetwork", "oncreate");
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor=sp.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        Log.d("hasNetwork", "onBind");

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (state == State.IDLE)
        {
            state = State.WORKING;
            this.wakeLock.acquire();
            // register location updates, not gonna code it you know
            Log.d("hasNetwork", "onStartCommand");
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        state = State.IDLE;
        if (this.wakeLock.isHeld())
        {
            Log.d("hasNetwork", "onDestroy");
            this.wakeLock.release();
        }
    }
    private void sendToServer()
    {
        // send to server in background thread. you might want to start AsyncTask here
        vollyRequest_Add_Latlong();

    }

    private void onSendingFinished()
    {
        // call this after sending finished to stop the service
        this.stopSelf(); 
   }
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by closed? Closed using "Force close" from settings?

Answer (score 0):

You are running into two different issues:

First, you are using [`setInexactRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). As the name implies and the documentation explicitly states, these alarms are inexact. Android will bundle multiple alarms together to minimize device wakeups.

If for whatever reason you believe that your use case requires exact timing you can use [`setExact()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent) to schedule a one shot alarm and continue to schedule those alarms as necessary.

Second, Android 6.0 introduced [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), which helps to further minimize device wakeups when the device is not in use. The idea is that if the user isn't actively using their device, no apps should really need to be performing periodic work such as pulling down fresh news articles. Instead, when the user next picks up their device the alarms will trigger and your data will update.

If your app falls into the whitelisting guidelines in the doze documentation, you can ask your users to whitelist your app from battery optimizations.

Comment: alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60000, wakeupIntent);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, new Date().getTime(), 60000, wakeupIntent);

Comment: I also used these two but still there is a prblem

Comment: The code you just posted in your comment is nowhere in your original post. If the original post is not representative of your code, please update it. Also, `setRepeating()` is also inexact (all repeating alarms are).

Comment: see my edit i changed in my code and still it is not working

Comment: If you are running on Android 6.0+, did you also add your app to the battery optimizations whitelist as per the second half of my answer?

Comment: no i didnt add app to battery optimizations whitelist .is it necessary to add?

Comment: If you are running on Android 6.0+ and expect your alarm to function with exact timing while the device is not actively being used, yes. I didn't just write that for fun.

Comment: ohk thanx alot.